# Django rest framework Serializer: get source from POST request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to add data from a POST request to my serializer:

```
class DeviceSerializer(ModelSerializerWithFields):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        exclude = ("groups",)

    last_values = serializers.JSONField(source="get_graph_data", read_only=True)
```

How can I get the resulting values from passing a specific request to `get_graph_data`?

Ideally something like:

```
last_values = serializers.JSONField(source="get_graph_data", read_only=True, payload="{'foo':1, 'bar':15}")
```

but if not, at least a way to pass one value so I can edit the endpoint to take this specific case into account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include the information you want to pass to the serializer in the [serializers context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)
2. Use a [SerializerMethodField()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for your *last_values* field and call the method `get_graph_data` there with your payload.